# Cannot get FOR XML PATH to work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a terrible time trying to figure out how to add XML PATH to my code to concatenate some information, let alone understanding how XML PATH works.  I've spent the better part of the last two days working on this and would appreciate some help!!

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
Select Top 100 Percent Agreements.AgrmntID, Agreements.Description As
  AgrmntDesc, Agreements.Status, AgreementSchedules.SchedDate, DateName(dw,
  AgreementSchedules.SchedDate), LaborCodeTypes.Description As LaborCode,
  Customers.CustName, Customers.CompanyName, JobSites.SiteName,
  AgreementSchedules.AgrmntSchedID
From Agreements Inner Join
  AgreementTypes On Agreements.AgrmntTypeID = AgreementTypes.AgrmntTypeID
  Inner Join
  AgreementSchedules On Agreements.AgrmntID = AgreementSchedules.AgrmntID
  Inner Join
  Customers On Agreements.CustID = Customers.CustID Inner Join
  JobSites On Agreements.CustSiteID = JobSites.CustSiteID Left Outer Join
  LaborCodeTypes On AgreementSchedules.RepairID = LaborCodeTypes.RepairID
Where Agreements.Status = 2 And Month(AgreementSchedules.SchedDate) =
  Month(GetDate())
```

Sample Data:

```
| AgreementID | LaborCodeTypes.Description   | DateName(dw, AgreementSchedules.SchedDate)|
| - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|
| 1           | Landscaping                  | Tuesday                                   |
| 1           | Landscaping                  | Friday                                    |
| 1           | Sweeping                     | Monday                                    |
| 1           | Sweeping                     | Wednesday                                 |
| 1           | Sweeping                     | Friday                                    |
| 2           | Landscaping                  | Monday                                    |
```

Expected Output:

```
| AgreementID | LaborCode   | Days Of Week              |
| - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - |
| 1           | Landscaping | Tuesday, Friday           |
| 1           | Sweeping    | Monday, Wednesday, Friday |
| 2           | Landscaping | Monday                    |
```

I would greatly, greatly appreciate it if someone could help me.

Thank you in advance!!

Jamie S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;with C as
(
  select A.AgreementID,
         LCT.Description as LaborCode,
         Ags.ShedDate
  from Agreements as A
    inner join AgreementSchedules as AgS
      on A.AgreementID = AgS.AgreementID
    inner join LaborCodeTypes as LCT
      on AgS.RepairID = LCT.RepairID
  where A.[Status] = 2 and
        AgS.ShedDate >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0) and
        AgS.ShedDate < dateadd(month, 1+datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
)
select C1.AgreementID,
       C1.LaborCode,
       stuff((select ', '+datename(weekday, C2.ShedDate)
              from C as C2
              where C1.AgreementID = C2.AgreementID and
                    C1.LaborCode = C2.LaborCode
              order by C2.ShedDate
              for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') as [Days Of Week]
from C as C1
group by C1.AgreementID, C1.LaborCode;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac9b8/1/0)

Comment: Thank you very, very much... I'm coding inside another program (eg: it's not my database) and this code still wasn't working...  I sent it to the tech support and they said it should be working but isn't.  Ugh.  Anyway, thank you for taking the time!!

Comment: Try to add a `;` first, before `with`.

Answer (score 3):

> how XML PATH works

I will try to explain that using this setup:

```
create table Grp
(
  GrpID int primary key,
  Name varchar(10)
)

create table Item
(
  ItemID int identity primary key,
  Name varchar(10),
  GrpID int references Grp(GrpID)
)

insert into Grp values
(1, 'G1'),
(2, 'G2')

insert into Item values
('A', 1),
('B', 1),
('C', 1),
('D', 2),
('E', 2)
```

The goal is to create a result with a comma separated list of names for each group.

```
GroupName  ItemNames
---------- ----------
G1         A,B,C
G2         D,E
```

[FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173812.aspx) is used to turn a query result into XML documents or XML fragments.

This query will create a XML fragment.

```
select I.Name
from Item as I
for xml path(''), type
```

Result:

```
<Name>A</Name>
<Name>B</Name>
<Name>C</Name>
<Name>D</Name>
<Name>E</Name>
```

The query above can be used in a correlated sub-query to create the XML fragment for each group like this.

```
select G.Name as GroupName,
       (
         select I.Name
         from Item as I
         where G.GrpID = I.GrpID
         for xml path(''), type
       ) as ItemNames
from Grp as G
```

Result:

```
GroupName  ItemNames
---------- --------------------------------------------
G1         <Name>A</Name><Name>B</Name><Name>C</Name>
G2         <Name>D</Name><Name>E</Name>
```

You can then use the [value()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) function to extract the values in the XML.

```
select Name as GroupName,
       (
         select I.Name
         from Item as I
         where G.GrpID = I.GrpID
         for xml path(''), type
       ).value('.', 'varchar(max)') as ItemNames
from Grp as G
```

Result:

```
GroupName  ItemNames
---------- ----------
G1         ABC
G2         DE
```

To finish this you need to add comma as a separator and that can be done by adding a comma to every item name in the sub-query `select ','+I.Name`. It will leave you with an extra comma before the first value. You can use the [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function to remove that `STUFF(Value, 1, 1, '')`.

Final query:

```
select Name as GroupName,
       stuff((
         select ','+I.Name
         from Item as I
         where G.GrpID = I.GrpID
         for xml path(''), type
       ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as ItemNames
from Grp as G
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond!!  I still can't quite get it... I keep getting an "Invalid SELECT statement.  Unexpected token "for"..." error message, no matter what I try.  I checked the version type and it IS 2005.  What I don't understand is the "I" before "I.Name" and "I.GrpID"  As you'll see above, my field names have .'s in them already, could that be throwing it off??

Comment: The `I` and the `G` in the query is table aliases and is used to qualify the fieldnames. You can use an alias instead of the table name. I could help you with your actual query if you update your question with table structures, sample data and expected output using that sample data.

Comment: I believe I've included what you asked for, @Mikael.  Thank you for even taking the time to respond to my Comment - I'm usually pretty good at figuring-out code, but I just can't get this!!

Comment: I can't even get just a "simple" XML of Agreements.AgrmntID and Agreements.Description (both from the Agreements table) to work (compared to your above example, Agreements.AgrmntID is GroupName and Agreements.Description is ItemNames).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a different way to achieve the results you are looking for...

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT AgreementId, UPPER(Description), 1 AS IsLabor
    FROM Table
    WHERE ...
    UNION
    SELECT AgreementId, DateName AS Description, 0 AS IsLabor
    FROM Table
    WHERE ...
) x
ORDER BY AgreementId, IsLabor DESC, Description
```

This should output the following (the UPPER is just to emphasize the labor descriptions):

```
| AgreementId | Description | IsLabor |
---------------------------------------
| 1           | LANDSCAPING | 1       |
| 1           | Friday      | 0       |
| 1           | Tuesday     | 0       |
| 2           | SWEEPING    | 1       |
| 2           | Friday      | 0       |
| 2           | Monday      | 0       |
| 2           | Wednesday   | 0       |
```

Hopefully I understood your question and this will work.

Comment: Thank you!!  Except I was more looking for (and realized I should have illustrated it better... and now can't 'cause I'm in Comments and don't know how to) | AgreementID | LaborCode | Service Day | with the multiple Service Days concatenated so the sweeping guy can take a quick look at it.