# saving a query as a view get error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query which runs fine and with no problem!

```
SELECT [Q].sHost
    , LEFT([Q].sDescription, Len([Q].sDescription) - 1) AS [sDescription]
FROM (

    SELECT DISTINCT [Q2].sHost
        , (
            SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), [Q1].[sDescription]) + N', ' AS [text()]
            FROM (
                SELECT (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN (CHARINDEX('\', [sInstance]) = 0)
                                THEN [sInstance]
                            ELSE substring([sInstance], 0, CHARINDEX('\', [sInstance]))
                            END
                        ) AS sHost
                    , [sDescription]
                FROM [db_group].[dbo].[instanceCommentsList]
                ) AS [Q1]
            WHERE ([Q1].sHost = [Q2].sHost)
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ) [sDescription]
    FROM (
        SELECT (
                CASE 
                    WHEN (CHARINDEX('\', [sInstance]) = 0)
                        THEN [sInstance]
                    ELSE substring([sInstance], 0, CHARINDEX('\', [sInstance]))
                    END
                ) AS sHost
            , [sDescription]
        FROM [db_group].[dbo].[instanceCommentsList]
        ) AS [Q2]
    ) AS [Q]
```

when I save this query as a view, I get the following error

> Error in WHERE clause near '('.
>
> Error in WHERE clause near '='. Unable
>
> to parse query text.

not sure where is the problem!

it's saves any way and it kind of works, I can use it in a simple select query but I get a red line under the name of the view and when I put the mouse over I get this message

> The object name is invalid ....

and if I use it in a more complex query it does not work at all

EDIT:----------------------------------

after reading [Cannot get FOR XML PATH to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170032/cannot-get-for-xml-path-to-work) thanks to **SelectDistinct**'s comment

I fixed it but still get one more error!

> Error in WHERE clause near '('.
>
> Unable to parse query text.

here is the fixed code:

```
SELECT [Q].sHost
    , LEFT([Q].sDescription, Len([Q].sDescription) - 1) AS [sDescription]
FROM (

    SELECT DISTINCT [Q2].sHost
        , (
            SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [Q1].[sDescription]) + ', ' AS [text()]
            FROM (
                SELECT (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN (CHARINDEX('\', [sInstance]) = 0)
                                THEN [sInstance]
                            ELSE substring([sInstance], 0, CHARINDEX('\', [sInstance]))
                            END
                        ) AS sHost
                    , [sDescription]
                FROM [db_group].[dbo].[instanceCommentsList]
                ) AS [Q1]
            WHERE ([Q1].sHost = [Q2].sHost)
            FOR XML PATH(''), type
       ).value('.', 'varchar(max)') as [sDescription]
    FROM (
        SELECT (
                CASE 
                    WHEN (CHARINDEX('\', [sInstance]) = 0)
                        THEN [sInstance]
                    ELSE substring([sInstance], 0, CHARINDEX('\', [sInstance]))
                    END
                ) AS sHost
            , [sDescription]
        FROM [db_group].[dbo].[instanceCommentsList]
        ) AS [Q2]
    ) AS [Q]
```

Comment: Wonder if those backslashes need escaping?

Comment: but it works just fine when I run the query!, I will test it anyway

Comment: Try putting a commar between FOR XML PATH and [description] like:
 FOR XML PATH('')
            ), [sDescription]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170032/cannot-get-for-xml-path-to-work Mikael Eriksson explains how FOR XML PATH works, it may be your use of this that is causing the issue

Comment: SelectDistinct, I did try that, it does not work, I get an error, the whole thing is not working then!

Comment: @Data-Base You need to go through your parentheses carefully and make sure you have no straglers

Answer (score 0):

Try WHERE [Q1].sHost = [Q2].sHost instead of WHERE ([Q1].sHost = [Q2].sHost) .